# Word for "too irresistible to be kept as a secret"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Consider a scenario where a person encounters *something* or hears *something* (experiences *something*) and he realises that *something* should be kept as a secret based on ethics or by the nature of *something* itself. But *something* is so irresistible to be kept as a secret and eventually the person loses his patience and blurts it out to people.

I would like to know if I can denote such an event by a phrase or a word.

Ex:

> "Mr. X encountered a/an _______ event".

The blank should be filled with a phrase or a term that denotes, 
*an event that should have been kept as a secret, but due to irresistible circumstances, it came into light*

Also, the event is not irresistible for a specific person. It is associated with the nature of the event.

I am not able to find an exact scenario to be given as an example. But this is what that person would think about the event when he encounters: *Ah! This should be kept as a secret. But how can I? I cannot restrict myself from telling this*, and he tells it out.

How would one describe such events as?

Comment: I think you do not mean ***so** irresistible* but ***too** irresistible*.

Comment: Yes. You are right. Too irresistible.

Comment: An *unkeepable secret*? *Irresistible gossip*?

Comment: @bib I didn't know that *unkeepable* is a valid word. Even now there is a squiggly red line beneath the word. Even if it is valid and if it is the antonym of the word *keepable* which means, *something is worth to be kept*, then wouldn't *unkeepable* mean *not worthy*?

Comment: Also the event is not necessarily a *gossip*.

Comment: A colloquial way of saying it, but not in one word, would be "This event has to be shared" with a heavy emphasis on "has" orally or in bold or underlined in written form.

Comment: @P. O. But does that capture the *secret* part? It means that the event is so sensational that it needs to be shared.

Comment: It's not a recognized word, but it conveys the sense. If used, it would be a [neologism](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/neologism), a made up word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow stumbled upon the word *Irrepressible* and I guess that would be the right word for this question.

**Irrepressible** - [**M-W**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/irrepressible)

> Impossible to hold back, stop, or control

Answer (score 2):

The word is insuppressible.
"Mr. X encountered an insuppressible secret."

Source: A Student Guide, Joyce: Ulysses, by Vincent Sherry of Villanova University, Cambridge University Press,  ISBN 10 0521-539765; Chapter 3, Lapsarian Languages; Page 97: "...like the insuppressible secret in the Freudian slip."

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a one-word solution, but I can suggest:

"The secret was too juicy to keep to him/herself."

Comment: Can you please explain your answer? Or can you at least provide a reference? Does *too juicy* capture the exact situation?

Comment: I can't find a wikitionary or OED reference for "juicy secret" but if you do a quick Google for the phrase you will find some examples of how it is used. I think that "too juicy" does indeed serve your purpose - but it is the secret itself which is juicy, and not the event that happened. You might also consider the event to be "[too] gossip-worthy to be kept as a secret".

Comment: Of course, it's in the dictionary: https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/juicy you are free to incorporate it into your answer

Comment: @Helmar I was searching for "juicy secret" which is why I didn't find the entry for "juicy gossip". Maybe "juicy gossip" is in more frequent use?

Comment: I think you can just use *juicy* with a link to the definition that @Helmar provided (or another if you find one you like better) and maybe a couple of the example usages that you've found. I think *juicy* is used with *gossip* and *secret* and "*piece of gossip*" and *tidbit* and *item* and so forth, which actually makes it a pretty good one-word answer to the question (if appropriately explained etc.).

Answer (score 1):

The following is used in practice and is applicable to your context

- spill the beans
- let the cat out of the bag
- whistle blowing

Answer (score 0):

Something happened that Mr. X couldn't **keep to himself**.

or

Something happened that Mr. X couldn't **keep quiet about**.